# Why interpreter show undefined as NULL?

Tags: php, interpreter, var-dump

Last time I'm exploring PHP pretty much and I was curious if it's possible to define variable without initializing it like in C++.

Well interpreter doesn't output an fatal eror (only a notice that variable test is undefined) if I'll run this code:

```
<?php 

$test = (int) $test;

?>
```

And if I try to check it with var_dump() function i get:

```
int(0)
```

I assumed interpreter automatically cast undefined to integer. Well, ok it's pretty clever.
But when I removed code repsonsible for type casting and checked it with var_dump() function I get:

```
NULL
```

Well, ok. So when I assign undefined variable as undefined variable I get variable with NULL. I can understand interpreter do it for me on the run. But when I try something like this:

```
<?php

var_dump($test);
var_dump($test);

?>
```

I get two notices that test is not defined, but var_dump() returns NULL, not undefined. And now I don't get it. If I'll turn off notices var_dump() function will have same result with undefined variables and variables assigned to NULL. And here comes a question from topic. Why interpreter (or rather a var_dump() function) treats undefined and NULL as same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is the only possible value of type NULL.
>
> A variable is considered to be null if:
> it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> **it has not been set to any value yet**.
> it has been unset().

`(int)$test` = casting, force a value to data type (integer)

warning notices = cause by $test is never defined, and you trying to use it

var_dump($test) = I dun have a value for $test, so, I return you a null (by PHP)

Comment: Also, PHP does not have a separate 'undefined' value like javascript. The variable is undefined, but the value of an undefined variable is NULL.

Comment: "value of an undefined variable" sounds a little strange as undefined variables don't have any value. Well, anyway I understand what you guys ment. It was a little surprising for me. Thanks a lot for your answers.